# Play video playlist using HTML(4)/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking at creating an app where the user can select multiple videos from a list of options and then play them in sequence one after the other.

In effect creating a video playlist.

Due to the current penetration % of browsers that can display HTML5 I'm wondering if this is possible using only HTML4/Javascript, and if so, are there any examples online.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Can you create a youtube playlist and play the videos back to back?

Comment: Yes. You didn't say, "w/o reloading page".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately HTML4 did not have support for video. The most common way of supporting older platforms is to use a polyfill, a javascript library that implements HTML5 features for browsers that don't have them.

A good video polyfill is [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/). This will use HTML5 on browsers that support it, and fall back to flash for browsers that don't.

To implement playlist functionality, you would have to listen for the "ended" event and then switch the source of the video to the next video.